# How use UrlRewriteFilter to use querystring?

Tags: rest, url-rewriting, resteasy

I am trying use UrlRewriteFilter, but, I'm not getting create a rule where I can turn this:

```
/bookmark-edit/1
```

in this:

```
/bookmark-edit.jsp?id=1
```

Examples are welcome!

Thanks,
Luciano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<rule>
    <from>^/bookmark-edit/(.*)$</from>
    <to>/bookmark-edit.jsp?id=$1</to>
</rule>
```